# Which are more beneficial: lyophilized or hydrolized collagen peptides?

Tags: molecular-biology, amino-acids

Looking at two different manufacturing methods for collagen peptides: hydrolyzed vs lyophilized (freeze dried), I read that hydrolyzed results in a **hydrophobic biolayer molecule collagen peptide**.

Re: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-hydrolyzed-collagen-and-natural-collagen

> There is a big difference between types of collagen or natural
>   collagen available on the market. The main collagen sold is cheap
>   hydroyzed collagen, which is produced by extreme heat. And the
>   opposite end of the scale if lyophilized collagen which is freeze
>   dried and more delicate expensive processing. The collagen known as
>   natural collagen retains its triple helix and is an active collagen
>   very similar to that of humans. This natural collagen is derived from
>   fish skins of fresh water fish like silver carp.

Lyophilization process:  https://www.rdmag.com/article/2017/03/lyophilization-basics

While this may be quickly absorbed through the GI tract, thus "FASTEST ABSORBENT", does this hydrophobic biolayer hinder hydrolized collagen's ability to be broken down into amino acids - which is what we want out of them, right?  Or is it that lypholization retains its triple helix?

I'm not entirely clear on all the terminology, but essentially I would like to know which one is actually better and used by the body, rather than marketing "fastest absorbed by the body".

Additional reference:

- [US National Library of Medicine National Institutes of Health - lyophilization vs hydrolyzed collagen](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/?term=lyophilization%20vs%20hydrolyzed%20collagen)
- [Collagen Type I, salmon](https://www.exalpha.com/product/collagen-type-i-salmon/)

If down-voting, please provide a reason.

Comment: Please do not continue reposting the same question. You should instead *edit* questions to preserve their history.

Comment: I changed  the question

Comment: Is anyone actually interested in answering the question?

Comment: "Hydrophobic bilayer" is not related to collagen supplements but to cell membranes, in this case, apparently to intestinal cell membranes. That part is confusing, so if you do not know where you have read it, I suggest to remove that.

Answer (score 1):

I have found no evidence that lyophylization of collagen "retains its triple helix." And even if it does, this is not important for its effectiveness, because collagen needs to be digested (broken down) into individual amino acids or peptides before absorption, which means that any triple helix would be be gone at that point.

> The first step in digestion consists of **degradation of hydrolyzed
>   collagen to form dipeptides and tripeptides or free amino acids.**
>   Several proteases (eg, pancreatic proteases, small intestinal
>   brush-border proteases, peptidase) are involved in the degradation
>   process *([Clinical Inteventions In Aging, 2014](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4206255/)).*

The point of lyophylization colagen is not to improve its digestion or bioavailability, but to extend its shelf life.

> Lyophilization enables longer shelf life, often as long as two-five
>   years and makes it much easier to transport the product. In addition,
>   products can be stored at room temperature  *([rdmag.com](https://www.rdmag.com/article/2017/03/lyophilization-basics))*.

You can also see that "hydrolyzed" and "lyophilized" do not exclude each other, because ["Lyophilized Collagen Hydrolysate"](https://www.amazon.com/Boxes-Bioplus-Diet-Pill-Bioflavonoid/product-reviews/B00MV5J6PC) is being sold.